# Alexa skill, custom slot - date and time

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I've created a skill and i want to be able to call upon a machine state at a certain date and time from my dynamo db table.

my first column is date and my sort key is time.

Would i need to create a custom slot for date with all 365 daysof the year or is there a quicker way to do this? Also would i need to create a custom slot for every minute of the day.

Code:

```js
var AWSregion = 'us-east-1';  // us-east-1
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
AWS.config.update({
    region: "'us-east-1'"
});

let GetMachineStateIntent = (context, callback) => {    
  var params = {
    TableName: "updatedincident",
    Key: {
      date: "2018-03-28",
      time: "04:23",
    }
  };
  dbClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       // failed to read from table for some reason..
       console.log('failed to load data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       // let skill tell the user that it couldn't find the data 
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "the data could not be loaded from your database",
          endSession: false
       });
    } else {
       console.log('loaded data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(data.Item, null, 2));
       // assuming the item has an attribute called "incident"..
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: data.Item.incident,
          endSession: false
       });
    }
  });
};


function sendResponse(context, callback, responseOptions) {
  if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    context.succeed(buildResponse(responseOptions));
  } else {
    callback(null, buildResponse(responseOptions));
  }
}

function buildResponse(options) {
  var alexaResponse = {
    version: "1.0",
    response: {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.output}</prosody></speak>`
      },
      shouldEndSession: options.endSession
    }
  };
  if (options.repromptText) {
    alexaResponse.response.reprompt = {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.reprompt}</prosody></speak>`
      }
    };
  }
  return alexaResponse;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    var request = event.request;
    if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
        output: "welcome to my skill. what data are you looking for?",
        endSession: false
      });
  }
    else if (request.type === "IntentRequest") {
      let options = {};         
      if (request.intent.name === "GetMachineStateIntent") {
        GetMachineStateIntent(context, callback);
      } else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" || request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "ok. good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
      else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.HelpIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "you can ask me about incidents that have happened",
          reprompt: "what can I help you with?",
          endSession: false
        });
      }
      else {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! please try again!",
          endSession: false
        });
      }
    }
    else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, ""); // no response needed
    }
    else {
      // an unexpected request type received.. just say I don't know..
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! please try again!",
          endSession: false
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error by logging it and sending back an failure
    console.log('Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler!', e);
    if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
       context.fail("Unexpected error");
    } else {
       callback("Unexpected error");
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is *no*

In your interaction model you can supply the following built in slot types for your date and time slots:

- built-in Date slot: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#date
- built-in Time slot: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#time

The docs explain what type of utterances map to each.

For instance, you could create an interaction model where you set up an intent, let's call it `GetMachineStateIntent` and then map the following utterances to this model:

```
what was the machine state at {Time} on {Date}
what was the state of the machine at {Time} on {Date}
what was the machine state at {Time} {Date}
what was the state of the machine at {Time} {Date}
what was the machine state on {Date} at {Time} 
what was the state of the machine on {Date} {Time} 
what was the machine state {Date} at {Time} 
what was the state of the machine {Date} {Time}
```

In your skill, you would handle the `GetMachineStateIntent` and in the request you will receive the filled in values for each of the two slots.

As a first step, while building the interaction model, it would be good to have Alexa simply respond back with speech confirming that it received the date and time slot values from your request.

For example, you might include something like:

```
if (request.type === "IntentRequest" && request.intent.name == "GetMachineStateIntent") {
    var dateSlot = request.intent.slots.Date != null ?
                   request.intent.slots.Date.value : "unknown date";
    var timeSlot = request.intent.slots.Time != null ?
                   request.intent.slots.Time.value : "unknown time";

    // respond with speech saying back what the skill thinks the user requested
    sendResponse(context, callback, {
      output: "You wanted the machine state at " 
                + timeSlot + " on " + dateSlot,
      endSession: true
    });
```

}

Comment: Thank you, does it matter what format i have my date in? Because atm i have day/month/year and my skill doesnt seem to be working

Comment: this is the current error im getting Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler! TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at exports.handler.e (/var/task/index.js:71:16), ive made sure to put my date in the ISO-8601 format also, my table is set up as follows

Comment: DATE | TIME | INCIDENT
and i have my function set to call back Incident 

       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: data.Item.incident,
          endSession: false
       });
    }
  });
};

Comment: Yes, the format matters. That is why I recommended you try to read back the format for the slot to see what Alexa provides to your skill in the slot. You will have to normalize that input and then query your table. Break your task into small chunks. 1) the interaction model - make sure that works correctly and as you expect in the skill; 2) make sure your lambda can query your dynamo table (that we covered in a different question); 3) work on the transforming the input from the Date and Time slots to match the input that Your DynamoDb table expects - this lat part has nothing to do with Dynamo

Comment: despite fixing the format i keep getting 'I don't know that one! please try again!' as my response and Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler! TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at exports.handler.e (/var/task/index.js:71:16) in cloud watch, not sure what it could be?

Comment: I understand; it seems like there is an issue with your skill code, most likely dereferencing the `request.type`; without knowing what your skill code looks like it's hard to say but the code example I gave above is based on the skill code from your previous question - the one that was working at one point. I simply modified it a bit but you have to make sure the `request` variable is set to the actual request from the event, like so: `var request = event.request;` where `event` is provided from `exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {`

Comment: ive updated my question to include my code, I haven't changed it much so not sure why this s happening

Comment: Quick question, i'm unsure as to whether my slot values are being sent to dynamodb, and I can't currently get alexa to call out my date, can you provide some direction

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what the problem is; you'll have to be more specific - consider asking a new question with complete details