# ASK error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a skill that will call back different incidents at different dates and times from a DynamoDB table through Alexa.

My 3 columns are data, time and incident

I've defined my partition and sort key in my Lambda function as

```js
let GetMachineStateIntent = (context, callback) => {    
  var params = {
    TableName: "updatedincident",
    Key: {
        date: "2017-03-21",
        time: "07:38",
        incident: "Blocked Primary",
    }
  };
```

When I try to test my skill I can't seem to recall the incident correctly, the error I'm getting in Cloudwatch is:

> 2018-03-28T14:48:53.397Z   042319cb-4a3e-49ae-8b33-1641367107d4    Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler! TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
>   at exports.handler.e (/var/task/index.js:70:16)

as well as:

> 2018-03-28T14:48:53.417Z   042319cb-4a3e-49ae-8b33-1641367107d4
>   {
>       "errorMessage": "Unexpected error"
>   }

Here is my code from index.js

```js
var AWSregion = 'us-east-1';  // us-east-1
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
AWS.config.update({
    region: "'us-east-1'"
});

let GetMachineStateIntent = (context, callback) => {    
  var params = {
    TableName: "updatedincident",
    Key: {
      date: "2018-03-28",
      time: "04:23",
    }
  };
  dbClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       // failed to read from table for some reason..
       console.log('failed to load data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       // let skill tell the user that it couldn't find the data 
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "the data could not be loaded from your database",
          endSession: false
       });
    } else {
       console.log('loaded data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(data.Item, null, 2));
       // assuming the item has an attribute called "incident"..
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: data.Item.incident,
          endSession: false
       });
    }
  });
};


function sendResponse(context, callback, responseOptions) {
  if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    context.succeed(buildResponse(responseOptions));
  } else {
    callback(null, buildResponse(responseOptions));
  }
}

function buildResponse(options) {
  var alexaResponse = {
    version: "1.0",
    response: {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.output}</prosody></speak>`
      },
      shouldEndSession: options.endSession
    }
  };
  if (options.repromptText) {
    alexaResponse.response.reprompt = {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.reprompt}</prosody></speak>`
      }
    };
  }
  return alexaResponse;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    var request = event.request;
    if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
        output: "welcome to my skill. what data are you looking for?",
        endSession: false
      });
  }
    else if (request.type === "IntentRequest") {
      let options = {};         
      if (request.intent.name === "GetMachineStateIntent") {
        GetMachineStateIntent(context, callback);
      } else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" || request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "ok. good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
      else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.HelpIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "you can ask me about incidents that have happened",
          reprompt: "what can I help you with?",
          endSession: false
        });
      }
      else {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! please try again!",
          endSession: false
        });
      }
    }
    else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, ""); // no response needed
    }
    else {
      // an unexpected request type received.. just say I don't know..
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! please try again!",
          endSession: false
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error by logging it and sending back an failure
    console.log('Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler!', e);
    if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
       context.fail("Unexpected error");
    } else {
       callback("Unexpected error");
    }
  }
};
```

and this is my handler GetMachineState.js

```js
function sendResponse(context, callback, responseOptions) {
  if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    context.succeed(buildResponse(responseOptions));
  } else {
    callback(null, buildResponse(responseOptions));
  }
}

function buildResponse(options) {
  var alexaResponse = {
    version: "1.0",
    response: {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.output}</prosody></speak>`
      },
      shouldEndSession: options.endSession
    }
  };
  if (options.repromptText) {
    alexaResponse.response.reprompt = {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.reprompt}</prosody></speak>`
      }
    };
  }
  return alexaResponse;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    var request = event.request;
    if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
        output: "welcome to my skill. what do you want to find?",
        endSession: false
      });
    }
    else if (request.type === "IntentRequest") {
      let options = {};         
      if (request.intent.name === "GetMachineStateIntent") {
        // this is where we will wire up the dynamo call
        // for now, just send a simple response and end the session
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "cinema not implemented yet!",
          endSession: true
        });
      } else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" || request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "ok. good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
      else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.HelpIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "you can ask me about incidents that have happened",
          reprompt: "what can I help you with?",
          endSession: false
        });
      }
      else {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
    }
    else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, ""); // no response needed
    }
    else {
      // an unexpected request type received.. just say I don't know..
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error by logging it and sending back an failure
    console.log('Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler!', e);
    if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
       context.fail("Unexpected error");
    } else {
       callback("Unexpected error");
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible to know for sure if this is the problem or not because you haven't shared the code from the *index.js* file. The error message you get is telling you that the problem occurs at line 70 in your index.js file so you should look there, and figure out what the problem is.

However, based on the fact that you also posted this as a comment on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526496/63074), I'm going to venture to guess that the issue you've run into is that you used the code snippet I provided in [the answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526496/63074) and the error is from dereferencing the `request.type`

You have to make sure the request variable is set to the actual request from the event, like so: `var request = event.request` where event is provided from `exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {`

For example:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  var request = event.request;
  if (request.type === "IntentRequest" 
      // make suret the name of the intent matches the one in your interaction model
   && request.intent.name == "GetMachineStateIntent") {
    var dateSlot = request.intent.slots.Date != null ?
                   request.intent.slots.Date.value : "unknown date";
    var timeSlot = request.intent.slots.Time != null ?
                   request.intent.slots.Time.value : "unknown time";

    // respond with speech saying back what the skill thinks the user requested
    sendResponse(context, callback, {
       output: "You wanted the machine state at " 
              + timeSlot + " on " + dateSlot,
       endSession: true
    });
  } else {
    // TODO:  handle other types of requests..
    sendResponse(context, callback, {
       output: "I don't know how to handle this request yet!"
       endSession: true
    }); 
  } 
};

function sendResponse(context, callback, responseOptions) {
  if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    context.succeed(buildResponse(responseOptions));
  } else {
    callback(null, buildResponse(responseOptions));
  }
}

function buildResponse(options) {
  var alexaResponse = {
    version: "1.0",
    response: {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.output}</prosody></speak>`
      },
      shouldEndSession: options.endSession
    }
  };
  if (options.repromptText) {
    alexaResponse.response.reprompt = {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.reprompt}</prosody></speak>`
      }
    };
  }
  return alexaResponse;
}
```

Comment: Hi mike, i've added my index.js as well as my handler to this question, man i really hope you have the best easter!

Comment: so why do you have two files?  index.js an GetMachineState.js?  what's the second one used for?  and how are you testing the skill? using Alexa, or some other way?

Comment: GetMachineState.js is my handler i believe, and i am testing using the alexa developer console, sorry for the late reply have had alot going on

Comment: i posted another question in more detail

Comment: okay i've re read all your replies and have successfully got a response acknowledging my date and time inputs, the response i got was 'You wanted the machine state at 04:23 on 2018-03' to which i replied yes and get no response instead of the state, any ideas?

Comment: It depends on how you want it to work. You could modify the reply to give the sate of the machine instead of repeating/confirming the question. Or, if you keep the confirmation, you could add the AMAZON.YesIntent to your interaction model and handle it in your skill to return the answer. For the latter you will also have to open the microphone to record the user’s response which can be done by setting shouldEndSession to false in the response that you have so far. You would also have to store the query parameters in skill session attributes for that as well.  A bit more complicated all in all.

Comment: I'd prefer to work towards the latter, could i also add AMAZON.Nointent and add functionality to repeat the question if the confirmation is wrong? Also how do i store query parameters so that i can get the state of the machine at my specified date and time? thanks again

Comment: Yes, of course. And like I said, probably the easiest way to get the query persisted would be to use session attributes. Have a look at this blog post. It discusses the use of session attributes for a similar task: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/2279543b-ed7b-48b4-a3aa-d273f7aab609/alexa-skill-recipe-using-session-attributes-to-enable-repeat-responses

Comment: I've managed to get it to understand my yes intent and no intent however i keep getting the response 'i dont know that one please try again' however i know my data is in the dynamo table

Comment: any guidance you can offer? I have a deadline to complete the project by Tuesday so anything would be appreciated

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m traveling next few days. Not sure how much I can help.